# Tensorflow: Tensor with inconsistent dimension size?

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow, object-detection

I've been implementing a convolutional neural network for object detection and I met the issue below:

For object detection task, usually, one input image is associated with an undetermined number of object bounding boxes. Each bounding box can be represented by 4 coordinates. Thus, to represent bounding boxes as a tensor, the shape will be:

```
[batch_size, variable_num_bbox(?), 4]
```

Note that here, it's not just that **variable_num_bbox** can't be specified before the graph construction, but also, even within one batch input, different images can have different numbers of bounding boxes.

As an illustrative example, I would like to convert the following array into a tensor:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]], [[3, 4, 5, 6]]]
```

Here, **variable_num_bbox**=2 for the first image, but it's 1 for the second image.

I've tried and failed several ways to convert the above nested list to a tensor, which leads me to the question whether tensorflow support tensors with inconsistent dimension size? If no, is there any plan to support it to give developers such flexibility? And if it's not going to be supported, is there a way to by-pass this issue for object detection task? One solution would be to set **batch_size=1** , and a bounding box can be represented as a tensor with shape **[variable_num_bbox(?), 4]**, so yes, the dimension inconsistency is gone, but that will hurt the efficiency significantly.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to deal with this issue is to generate a list of bounding boxes when needed. For example, if you have all bounding boxes in a 4D tensor (ie the same number of bounding boxes per image) and want to perform non-maximum suppression (which will generally result in a variable number of boxes per image) you could use something like this:

```
bbox_list = []
for i, bboxes in enumerate(tf.unpack(bboxes_batch, axis=0)):
    idx = tf.image.non_max_suppression(bboxes, confidences[i], 20)
    bbox_list.append(tf.gather(bboxes, idx))
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring reply. But in my case, I need to load ground truth bounding boxes for training, and it might not be practical to load all the gt bboxes into one tensor and sample from it for each image. But definitely, it makes sense to represent bounding boxes as a **list of tensors**, which is more flexible.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting that you use a list of tensors (bounding boxes). The conversion from a 4D tensor was just an example of a situation that occurs in some forms of object detection like YOLO, SSD, etc.